# How to unescape string property in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm trying to bend my head around the following. I have a WebAPI service that returns MediaInfo like so:

```
public List<MediaInfo> Get(string id)
```

Where MediaInfo is just a DTO as:

```
public class MediaInfo
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Folder{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the Folder property there is a path stored, something like "\\10.x.x.x\share\foldername"

When the result comes back from WebAPI the backslashes are escaped like so:

```
[
  {
    "File": "GBHIST002242_RUS_xxx_HD_1.mp4",
    "Folder": "\\\\10.x.x.x\\share\\folder\\Archive"
  }
]
```

I can't seem to get WebAPI or JSON.Net to not escape the contents of Folder. How can I get the WebAPI / JSON.Net formatter to leave the Folder property alone?

[UPDATE]: See my answer below

Comment: Shouldn't `\10.x.x.x\share\foldername` be `\\10.x.x.x\share\foldername` ? I couldn't explain how you'd get from one backslash to 4 just per escaping. And if you print the folder string to screen, everything should be fine again.

Comment: Yes, that's an escaping issue with the stackoverflow.com formatter :-), will fix in the question. Also, the result is directly copied from the screen (chrome). When I use IE I can save the Json in a text file and that also contains the duplicate backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, the extra backslashes are there for a reason: without them it's no longer valid json. see Serialising a string which contains backslashes with Json.Net

Also when you modify the json to the desired (incorrect) format and validate that in something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you get validations errors.

So all in all this just lack of knowledge in JSON.

Comment: So, in answer to the original question, how to unescape the string: just deserialize the JSON normally!